# Not able to get Devices information from Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

My Dropbox account has been connected/synced with various devices.I want to get the devices information like most recent activities.
I tried Dropbox's HTTP API endpoints as explained in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation.
But I am not able to get the devices information.Please someone help to get the devices information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to get the device information for the linked user account. We'll consider it a feature request.

Note that the Dropbox Business API does offer this functionality, but that's only available for Business accounts:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team-devices-list_member_devices